# Inclusao de dados/ objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tendo um problema na inclusão de objetos oriundos de outras classes. Qual seria a melhor solução para isso?

Por exemplo, tenho uma classe de Servico e atributos que são outras classes, como Cliente e Veiculo. Tal qual listada abaixo:

```
public class Servico
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
        public Veiculo  veiculo{ get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; } 
        public DateTime DataServico { get; set; }
        
        public Servico()
       {
        new Cliente(),
        new Veiculo()
        }
   
    }
```

Além disso tenho o método dentro do `controller` que irá fazer a inclusão dos dados e receber os objetos.
Como demonstro logo abaixo...

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("Incluir")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Incluir(Servico servico)
        {
            try
            {
                bool res = false;

                if (servico == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("servico");
                }

                Conexao cx = new Conexao();
                cx.ConectarBase();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = cx.connection;
                command.CommandText = "EXEC INCLUIR_SERVICO @NOME, @DESCRICAO, @CLIENTE, @VEICULO, @VALOR";

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("nome", servico.Nome);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("descricao", ((object)servico.Descricao) ?? DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("cliente", ((object)servico.veiculo.Id) ?? DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("veiculo", ((object)servico.cliente.Id) ?? DBNull.Value);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("valor", ((object)servico.Valor) ?? DBNull.Value);

                int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                res = i > 0;

                cx.DesconectarBase();

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
            }

        }
```

Entretanto, nos objetos tenho erro de null exception nas propriedades Servico.Cliente.Id e Servico.Veiculo.ID.

Por gentileza, alguém pode me ajudar a entender como devo resolver esta questão?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro de *null exception* ocorre quando a instância de um objeto referencia nulo, ou seja, não referencia nenhuma posição de objeto na memória. Você obteve esse porque, no construtor da classe *Servico*, apenas instanciou objetos da classe *Cliente* e *Veiculo*, mas não os associou aos atributos *Cliente* e *Veiculo*, respectivamente. Para resolver o erro, é necessário associar os atributos às instâncias:

```
public class Servico
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public Cliente cliente { get; set; }
    public Veiculo  veiculo{ get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; } 
    public DateTime DataServico { get; set; }
    
    public Servico()
   {
       cliente = new Cliente();
       veiculo = new Veiculo();
    }

}
```